# Modifying jquery $.ajax() to handle received information by $_POST in php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Before asking my question, following is my html code(Edited):

```
<?php
$conn = //connected to db successfully.
$sql = "SELECT t1.column1 AS Column_1 FROM table1 t1";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
do{
?>
<button name="my_button" data-id="<?php echo $rows['Column_1']; ?>" type="submit"    onclick="my_function()">Click Me</button>
<?php }while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)); ?>
```

Following is the jquery ajax in my html header tag:

```
function my_function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'my_file.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data: {item_id : $('button[data-id]').attr('data-id')},
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I have a little general question:

Being very new to jquery and specially jquery ajax. What should I include in "data:" in jquery `$.ajax()` or how should I modify `$.ajax()` so I could both handle my button data-id tag value (which is 1 here) and my text input value/name by `$_POST` value in 'my_file.php'.
I receive 'undefined index item_id' alert error for php file using `$_POST["item_id"]` when I have `{ item_id : $(this).data("id")}` in $.ajax data. I appreciate your guiding me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: I changed the 'data' but the problem again persists.

Edit 2: I have edited my html doc. In my real html doc, I fetch the items with buttons in my html file by mysqli_fetch_assoc from my mysql database. (Please check my edited html code). The problem is, no matter which button I click on, the data-id that is inserted into my mysql table2 using 'my_file.php' file, is always one specific value. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('button[data-id]').attr('data-id')` instead of `$(this).data("id")`. Try this

```
function my_function(){
    $.ajax({
         url : 'my_file.php',
         type : 'POST',
         data: {item_id : $('button[data-id]').attr('data-id'), field1 : $('#field1').val()},
         success : function(data){
              alert(data);
         }
    });
 }
```

And in `my_file.php` get the `POST` values like this

```
$item_id = isset($_POST['item_id']) ? $_POST['item_id'] : ''; 
$field1 = isset($_POST['field1']) ? $_POST['field1'] : '';
echo  $item_id;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but again 'undefined index: item_id' error persists for 'my_file.php' file. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you change both `ajax data` & `PHP` end as I suggested? Post your updated codes.

Comment: Yes, I changed the 'data' in ajax and have used $_POST['item_id'] in 'my_file.php'.(Please note I've only used data-id attribute and haven't used the value of text input in the example above) but the'undefined index: item_id' error again persists for $_POST['item_id'] in the php file.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @AliS. i don't know what happened there but it works fine on my machine. Check by clearing your browser `cache, cookie`. You can use `isset` for hiding error but it will not give any returning value if it is not set.

Comment: Instead of `.attr('data-id');` use `.data('id');`

Comment: @user3659034 Sorry, a misspelling made the error persist. Just modified and that just worked. Do you have any suggestion for my Edit 2 above in my question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are welcome. That can be done by common `class`.

Answer (score 0):

you could catch the button click and do a return: false; then submit the data.
to send your textbox data you can go as below:

```
var field = $('#field1').val();
```

then

```
data: field,
```

you can also want to take a look at serialize function